# vue is not recognized on command line

Tags: vue.js

Relative newbie, working in vs code with large project; trying to get into vue.js.

I have installed npm (and node, obviously) globally and they are functioning well from windows 10 powershell, both within the vs code terminal or from separate directories.

I did:

1. `npm install - g vue/cli` and also
2. `npm install -g vue` and got messages that package was installed.

The problem is that if I enter `vue create test` (which I got from a video), I get a message that **"vue is not recognized"**.

This happens from the terminal within vs code or from the terminal in another directory. I tried this in the windows powershell and from the command prompt as well. Did I "over-install" the vue.js?

Comment: The official way to install Vue CLI is `npm install -g @vue/cli` as seen in the docs https://cli.vuejs.org/#getting-started; have you tried that?

Comment: yes, yuriy636, I typed as you mentioned (I just checked the video I'm working off - I'm that green with vue.js - sorry for the inconvenience.) That didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an environment variable like '..\AppData\Roaming\npm' manually.